# How to plot graph from json response with changing keys in android

Tags: android, json

I am a beginner in Android Development. I am making a project where one of the features of the app is to display a graph for the vaccine doses administered for each country using the JSON response received from the server. But the issue I am facing is that the date keys( with values as integer) are updated every day and I don't know how to display it as a graph. I am still learning and everything I have learned is with the help of tutorials. I want to display the data for the last 14 days. I have looked everywhere for ideas to solve this but I am not able to solve it.
The data looks like this

```
 [
  {
    "country": "Afghanistan",
    "timeline": {
      "4/8/21": 123714,
      "4/9/21": 128143,
      "4/10/21": 133286,
      "4/11/21": 139143,
      "4/12/21": 145714,
      "4/13/21": 153000,
      "4/14/21": 161000,
      "4/15/21": 169000,
      "4/16/21": 177000,
      "4/17/21": 185000,
      "4/18/21": 193000,
      "4/19/21": 201000,
      "4/20/21": 209000,
      "4/21/21": 217000,
      "4/22/21": 240000,
      "4/23/21": 240000,
      "4/24/21": 240000,
      "4/25/21": 240000,
      "4/26/21": 240000,
      "4/27/21": 240000,
      "4/28/21": 240000,
      "4/29/21": 240000,
      "4/30/21": 240000,
      "5/1/21": 240000,
      "5/2/21": 240000,
      "5/3/21": 240000,
      "5/4/21": 240000,
      "5/5/21": 240000,
      "5/6/21": 240000,
      "5/7/21": 240000
    }
  },
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To plot a graph. You have to do the following.

1. Fetch the data as an integer and store it in an array.
2. Use [GraphView](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView) to plot the data like this

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
          new DataPoint(0, 1),//There are the coordinates of your graph
          new DataPoint(1, 5),
          new DataPoint(2, 3),
          new DataPoint(3, 2),
          new DataPoint(4, 6)
});
graph.addSeries(series);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir. I will try to implement the method.

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer if it works..:D